# How to combine 2 series in area chart - Highchart

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, highcharts

I have tried to show 2 series of data in Area chart | Highcharts.  Its working fine but there is a whitespace between the series. How to remove the space?

Fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/alagarrk/0jcg5047/1/

```
series: [{
  name: 'Educated people',
  data: [{
    x: 0,
    y: 20000
  }, {
    x: 1,
    y: 19000
  }, {
    x: 2,
    y: 19000
  }, {
    x: 3,
    y: 18000
  }, {
    x: 4,
    y: 17000
  }, {
    x: 5,
    y: 16000
  }, {
    x: 6,
    y: 15000
  }, {
    x: 7,
    y: 14000
  }]
  }, {
  name: 'Uneducated people',
  data: [{
    x: 8,
    y: 13000
  }, {
    x: 9,
    y: 12000
  }, {
    x: 10,
    y: 11000
  }, {
    x: 11,
    y: 10000
  }]
}]
```

Please check and guide me to fix this issue

Comment: start the series 2 from the point series 1 finish with same value

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no "fixing" this issue, you don't have any data between point 7 and 8. What you can do is start series 2 (uneducated people) on point 7. That way it will look connected.

```
name: 'Uneducated people',
data: [{
  x: 7,
  y: 13000
}, {
  x: 8,
  y: 12000
...
```

**Working example:** http://jsfiddle.net/0jcg5047/2/

Comment: Thank you for your quick reply. But in this case, x:7 value is repeated in both series. Is this correct?

Comment: If you don't want there to be a gap between 7 and 8 on the x-axis, then yes. Look at the example